# Auto fill HTML Form with custom data

Tags: javascript, html, http-post, http-get

In my workplace, there is a web based workflow management system. My job is to upload documents to the system and follow up if the relavent department have completed the job. Department people view the documents and change the status from "uploaded" to "Assigned", "Completed", "Rejected" etc. 
I have to search the documents every time by entering the date range and clicking on search button in the form. 
Is there any way to make a shortcut like something where I don't have to feed the date every time. My requirement is to fill two date fields with today's date and click the search button automatically.

The said system is a simple web page with a form and uses HTTP POST method.

Edit:
In HTML-GET I can pass whatever I want with URL, like on google if I want to search "stackoverflow" I can staright away type the url like "https://www.google.com/search?q=stackoverflow..."

Is such a thing possible in HTML-POST also.

Comment: Certainly sounds possible, do you have a code sample of the existing form?

Comment: this could help : http://benalexkeen.com/autofilling-forms-with-javascript/

Comment: Well, I don't have code of that system and have no access to it outside my office as well.

Comment: I have maked similar things with browser plugins usually in Chorme, thin about it.